# How to factor the following?

Tags: factoring, jacobian

Consider the Jacobian:

$$ J =  \begin{bmatrix} 
        -\frac{\beta I}{N} -\xi & -\frac{\beta S}{N} -\xi \\[1ex] \phantom{-}\frac{\beta I}{N} & \phantom{-}\frac{\beta S}{N} -\gamma  \end{bmatrix}. $$

Finding the eigenvalues of this matrix at its endemic equilibrium we have:

$$ \lambda_1=(-be-e^2 -   \sqrt[]{e} \sqrt[]{-4 b g^2 + 4 g^3 + b^2 e
    - 8 b g e + 8 g^2 e -     2 b e^2 + 4 g e^2 + e^3}/(2 (g + e))$$, $$\lambda_2=(-b e - e^2 +   \sqrt[]{e} \sqrt[]{-4 b g^2 + 4 g^3 + b^2 e - 8 b g e + 8 g^2 e -     2 b e^2 + 4 g e^2 + e^3}/(2 (g + e)$$

Where $b=\beta, \;g=\gamma,\; e=\xi$.

Mathematica wouldn't simplify(`Fullsimplify` doesn't work!) it to the following which I did by hand:

\begin{align} \lambda_1 &= \frac{-\xi\left(\beta +\xi\right) + \sqrt{\xi^2 \left(\beta +\xi\right)^2 -4\xi \left(\gamma+\xi\right)^2\left(\beta -\gamma\right)} }{2\left(\gamma + \xi\right)}, \\[2ex] \lambda_2 &= \frac{-\xi\left(\beta +\xi\right) - \sqrt{\xi^2 \left(\beta +\xi\right)^2 -4\xi \left(\gamma+\xi\right)^2\left(\beta -\gamma\right)} }{2\left(\gamma + \xi\right)}. \end{align}

Now my question is, how would I do something similar to the following:

**(i)**$$ J =  \begin{bmatrix} 
        -\frac{\beta I}{N} -\xi -\nu & -\frac{\beta S}{N} -\xi \\[1ex] \phantom{-}\frac{\beta I}{N} & \phantom{-}\frac{\beta S}{N} -\gamma -\nu  \end{bmatrix}. $$

Finding the eigenvalues at the endemic equilibrium we have:

$${(1/(2 (e + g + v)))(-b e - e^2 - b v - e v -     \sqrt[]{e + 
         v} \sqrt[]{b^2 e - 2 b e^2 + e^3 - 8 b e g + 4 e^2 g - 4 b g^2 + 
           8 e g^2 + 4 g^3 + b^2 v - 6 b e v + 5 e^2 v - 8 b g v + 
           16 e g v + 12 g^2 v - 4 b v^2 + 8 e v^2 + 12 g v^2 + 
           4 v^3},  (1/(  2 (e + g + v)))(-b e - e^2 - b v - e v +     \sqrt[]{e + 
         v} \sqrt[]{b^2 e - 2 b e^2 + e^3 - 8 b e g + 4 e^2 g - 4 b g^2 + 
           8 e g^2 + 4 g^3 + b^2 v - 6 b e v + 5 e^2 v - 8 b g v + 
           16 e g v + 12 g^2 v - 4 b v^2 + 8 e v^2 + 12 g v^2 + 4 v^3}}$$
where $b=\beta$, $e=\xi$, $g=\gamma$, and $v=\nu$.

**(ii)**$$ J =  \begin{bmatrix} 
        -\frac{\beta I}{N}  -\nu & -\frac{\beta S}{N} +\gamma  \\[1ex] -\sigma & -\gamma -\sigma-\nu  \end{bmatrix}. $$

Finding the eigenvalues at the endemic equilibria we have:

$$(1/(2 m (g + m + v)))(-g^2 m - b m^2 - g m^2 - m^3 - 2 g m v - 
  2 m^2 v - m v^2 - 
  m \sqrt[]{g^4 - 2 b g^2 m + 6 g^3 m + b^2 m^2 - 6 b g m^2 + 
      11 g^2 m^2 - 2 b m^3 + 6 g m^3 + m^4 + 8 g^3 v - 4 b g m v + 
      28 g^2 m v - 4 b m^2 v + 28 g m^2 v + 8 m^3 v + 18 g^2 v^2 - 
      2 b m v^2 + 38 g m v^2 + 18 m^2 v^2 + 16 g v^3 + 16 m v^3 + 
      5 v^4}, (1/(2 m (g + m + v)))(-g^2 m - b m^2 - g m^2 - m^3 - 
  2 g m v - 2 m^2 v - m v^2 + 
  m \sqrt[]{(g^4 - 2 b g^2 m + 6 g^3 m + b^2 m^2 - 6 b g m^2 + 
      11 g^2 m^2 - 2 b m^3 + 6 g m^3 + m^4 + 8 g^3 v - 4 b g m v + 
      28 g^2 m v - 4 b m^2 v + 28 g m^2 v + 8 m^3 v + 18 g^2 v^2 - 
      2 b m v^2 + 38 g m v^2 + 18 m^2 v^2 + 16 g v^3 + 16 m v^3 + 
      5 v^4}$$

where $b=\beta$, $m=\sigma$, $g=\gamma$, and $v=\nu$.

How can I factor the above like in the first example?

**ADDENDUM**

**(iii)**$$ J =  \begin{bmatrix} 
        -\frac{\beta I}{N}  -\nu & -\frac{\beta S}{N}   \\[1ex] -\sigma & -\sigma-\nu  \end{bmatrix}. $$

Once again, finding the eigenvalues at the endemic equilibria we have

$$ (-b m^2 - m^3 - 2 m^2 v - m v^2 - m \sqrt[]{b^2 m^2 - 2 b m^3 + m^4 - 4 b m^2 v + 8 m^3 v - 2 b m v^2 + 18 m^2 v^2 + 16 m v^3 + 5 v^4})/(2 m (m + v)), (-b m^2 - m^3 - 2 m^2 v - m v^2 + m \sqrt[]{b^2 m^2 - 2 b m^3 + m^4 - 4 b m^2 v + 8 m^3 v - 2 b m v^2 + 
   18 m^2 v^2 + 16 m v^3 + 5 v^4})/(2 m (m + v))
$$

Using `Fullsimplify` we have

$$-((b m + (m + v)^2 + \sqrt[]{
  b^2 m^2 - 2 b m (m + v)^2 + (m + v)^3 (m + 5 v)})/(2 (m + v))), -((
 b m + (m + v)^2 - \sqrt[]{
  b^2 m^2 - 2 b m (m + v)^2 + (m + v)^3 (m + 5 v)})/(2 (m + v)))$$

Considering Blue's solution to my other problems, is this the simplest it will get?

**ADDENDUM 2**

**(iv)**$$ J =  \begin{bmatrix} 
        -\frac{\beta I}{N}  -\nu & -\frac{\beta S}{N}   \\[1ex] \frac{\beta I}{N} & \frac{\beta S}{N} - \gamma - \nu  \end{bmatrix}. $$

Once again, finding the eigenvalues at the endemic equilibria we have

$$ (-b v - \sqrt[]v
   \sqrt[]{-4 b g^2 + 4 g^3 + b^2 v - 8 b g v + 12 g^2 v - 4 b v^2 + 
   12 g v^2 + 4 v^3})/(2 (g + v)), (-b v + 
 \sqrt[]v \sqrt[]{-4 b g^2 + 4 g^3 + b^2 v - 8 b g v + 12 g^2 v - 
   4 b v^2 + 12 g v^2 + 4 v^3})/(2 (g + v))
$$

Using `Fullsimplify` we have

$$-((b v + \sqrt[]v \sqrt[]{b^2 v - 4 b (g + v)^2 + 4 (g + v)^3})/(
 2 (g + v))), 
(-b v + \sqrt[]v \sqrt[]{b^2 v - 4 b (g + v)^2 + 4 (g + v)^3})/(2 (g + v))$$

Comment: Mathematical modelling of infectious diseases?

Comment: @Deepak : Yes, correct.

Comment: Is the symbol $I$ meaning $\sqrt{-1}$ ?

Comment: No, $I$ is the infection parameter

Comment: Then what is the equilibrium point $(S^*,I^*)$ ?

Comment: \begin{align*}
e_2 : \left( S_2^*, I_2^*, R_2^*\right)&= \left(\frac{N\left(\gamma + \nu\right)}{\beta}, \frac{N\left(\gamma+\nu \right) \left( \xi + \nu \right) \left( \frac{\beta}{\gamma+\nu} -1 \right) }{\beta\left(\gamma + \xi+\nu \right)}, \frac{\gamma N\left(\gamma+\nu \right)\left( \frac{\beta}{\gamma+\nu} -1 \right) }{\beta\left(\gamma + \xi+\nu \right)}\right)\\&=\left(\frac{N}{\mathcal{R}_0}, \frac{aN}{\mathcal{R}_0}\left(\mathcal{R}_0-1\right),\frac{bN}{\mathcal{R}_0}\left(\mathcal{R}_0-1\right) \right)
\end{align*}

Comment: Can't you remove this unnecessary variable renaming ?

Comment: For (i), I get to $$\frac{-h k \mp \sqrt{\;k (h^2 k + 4 (g-h + k) (g+k)^2\;}}{2(g + k)}$$
where $h:=b+e$ and $k:=e+v$. Does something like that help?

Comment: No, don't like.

Comment: @Blue Yes, I like it in a compact form like the one you provided.

Comment: @Math: With (iii), I might be inclined to write the radical expression as $$(bm-(m+v)^2)^2+4v(m+v)^3$$ The trick in all this is just recognizing "perfect squares" waiting to be completed. In this case, seeing $b^2m^2-2bm(m+v)^2$ makes me think of $p^2-2pq$, where $p:=bm$ and $q:=(m+v)^2$. This would be $(p-q)^2$ if only we could find $q^2$ ... that is, $(m+v)^4$. Conveniently, $$(m+v)^3(m+5v)=(m+v)^3(m+v+4v)=(m+v)^4+4v(m+v)^3$$ allowing us to complete the square and leave a not-unpleasant extra bit.

Comment: @Blue could you post the complete solution in your answer below. I will give you the bounty and accepted answer! Once again, thanks for helping :)

Comment: BTW: If I'd racked-up four examples of a problem like this, I'd want to start looking for patterns in the solutions in hopes of saving myself some simplifying trouble at the end. To do this, I'd try define my problem as broadly as possible. I'm not sure what that entails in your situation, because I don't know what "endemic equilibria" are or how to apply them. Nevertheless, rather than have Mathematica compute eigenvalues (usually in a form that's not as simplified as I'd like), I'd probably look first at the corresponding characteristic equation to see what might be simplified there.

Comment: @Blue : From your former comment, I understand what you did but since I'm a little stressed, I can't see the "tricks" I would normally see.. I totally agree with your latter comment. The characteristic polynomial is huge so that's why I shove it all in Mathematica and try simplifying at the end. If you can put (iii) in your answer, it'll look nice for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @Math: Come to think of it, (iii) is just (ii) with $g=0$. (Well, it is according to your rendering of the roots. The lower-right entries of the corresponding $J$ matrices disagree about the sign fo $\sigma$.) At this point, I'd rather see as broad a form of this problem as possible than continue to focus on particular instances. Are those $(S^\star, I^\star, R^\star)$ values in an earlier comment as bad as things get? can you provide the "huge" characteristic polynomial? (We may have different ideas of "huge". I regularly wrangle with polynomials with tens of thousands of terms.)

Comment: @Blue : I made a typo, this is indeed the case. (ii) being the SEIS model and (iii) being the SEI model. "I to S" state is determined by $\gamma$. No, things do get worse is higher dimensions. it'll be difficult to type it all out, but if you plug say, (ii) into wolfram and ask to calculate it's eigenvalues, you'll see a characteristic polynomial

Comment: Input $S$ and $I$ in the (ii) Jacobian as $S_2^*$ and $I_2^*$: $$e_2 : \left( S_2^*, I_2^*, R_2^*\right)= \left(\frac{N \left(\gamma+\nu\right)\left(\sigma+\nu \right)}{\beta \sigma}, \frac{N\left(\gamma+\nu\right)^2\left(\sigma+\nu\right)}{\beta\sigma \left(\gamma + \sigma+\nu\right)}\left(\frac{\beta\sigma}{\left(\gamma+\nu\right)\left(\sigma+\nu\right)}-1\right), \frac{N\sigma\left(\gamma+\nu\right)\left(\sigma+\nu\right)}{\beta\sigma \left(\gamma + \sigma+\nu\right)}\left(\frac{\beta\sigma}{\left(\gamma+\nu\right)\left(\sigma+\nu\right)}-1\right)\right)$$

Comment: @Blue : I'll be heading home now, I'll be back tomorrow should you have any questions.

Comment: @Math: ("Extended discussion" warning. This may be my last comment.) I don't get the Jacobian in (ii), with the above $S*$ and $I*$ substitutions, to yield the eigenvalues you gave without imposing additional relations on the parameters. Maybe I'm missing something. Be that as it may ... I guess the broadest solution requires a full description of the SEI/S model(s), which appears beyond the scope of discussion here, so I'll just leave my answer as-is and consider my contribution to this question complete. ... Cheers!

Comment: @Blue : If you'd like to discuss further, we can move into chat? I'm not sure why you didn't get the same eigenvalues with those substitutions, now I'm curios.. Shall we continue in chat?

Comment: (I don't chat.) Plugging $I^*$ & $S^*$ from your "Input $S$ and $I$ ..." comment into Jacobian (ii), Mathematica gives me char-polynomial $Ax^2+Bx+C$ where $$A=m(g+m+v)\quad C=(g+v)(g+m+v)(bm-(g+v)(m+v))$$ $$B=bgm+2gm^2+m^3-g^2v+bmv+gmv+3m^2v-2gv^2+mv^2-v^3$$ Comparing the Quadratic Formula $(-B\pm\sqrt{B^2-4AC})/(2A)$ w/your roots, I can deduce that we agree on $A$; but your $B$ is $$B=g^2m+bm^2+gm^2+m^3+2gmv+2m^2v+mv^2$$ which differs from mine by $$(g-m+v)(bm-(g+v)(m+v))$$ In order to agree, we'd need either $m=g+v$ or $bm=(g+v)(m+v)$. I don't see my error (but also don't deny making one).

Comment: I made a typo: it should read $(S_2^*, E_2^*, I_2^*)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (i), I get to $$\frac{-h k \mp \sqrt{\;h^2 k^2 + 4k\ell^2(\ell-h)\;}}{2\ell} \tag1$$
where $h:=b+e$, $k:=e+v$, $\ell:=e+g+v$.

For (ii),

$$\frac{
  - (p^2 + q)
   \mp \sqrt{
    (p^2 - q)^2
     + 4 v p^3
    }}{2 p}  \tag2$$
where $p:=g+m+v$ and $q:=m(b-g)$.

---

**Addendum.** OP has provided a bit of backstory to (ii), so I thought I'd use it to illustrate how sneaking-up on a solution can sometimes be easier than trying to find patterns in a final result generated by brute-force application of a computer algebra system. (This a common strategy for me.)

Take OP's Jacobian $J$ for (ii)
$$J = \begin{bmatrix}-\frac{bI}{N}-v & -\frac{bS}{N}+g \\ -m & -g-m-v\end{bmatrix} \tag{A.1}$$
and substitute
$$S\to \frac{N(g+v)(m+v)}{bm} \qquad I\to\frac{Nm(g+v)(m+v)}{bm(g+m+v)}\left(\frac{bm}{(g+v)(m+v)}-1\right) \tag{A.2}$$
Now, generally, if the `Eigenvalues` command (with `FullSimplify` or whatever) gives a pretty result, take it and run. If the result is a mess, step back and take a semi-manual approach. Here, use `CharacteristicPolynomial` to get a polynomial of the form $Ax^2+Bx+C$. The coefficients may still be messes, but they're *smaller* messes. To isolate them, use `CoefficientList` (with, say, `Factor`). The results in this case are
$$\begin{align}
A &= g+m+v \\
B &= g^2 + b m + g m + m^2 + 2 g v + 2 m v + v^2 \\
C &= (g + m + v) (b m - g m - g v - m v - v^2) 
\end{align} \tag{A.3}$$
The forms of $A$ and $C$ suggest that $g+m+v$ *wants* to be a unified quantity; let's call it $p$. Note that we can find less-obvious instances of $p$ elsewhere in the coefficients:
$$\begin{align}
A &= p &&= p\\
B &= b m + g^2 + m^2 + v^2 + g m + 2 g v + 2 m v &&= bm + p^2 - gm = (b-g)m+p^2 \\
C &= p (b m - g m - g v - m v - v^2) &&= p((b-g)m-pv)
\end{align} \tag{A.4}$$
*These* forms suggest that $(b-g)m$ *also* wants to be a unified quantity; call it $q$. So, we have:
$$A = p\qquad B=p^2+q \qquad C = p(q-pv)$$
From here, applying the Quadratic Formula is almost effortless, and we get
roots (ie, eigenvalues of $J$) of the form
$$\frac{-B\pm\sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}=\frac{-(p^2+q)\pm \sqrt{\Delta}}{2p} \tag{A.5}$$
where
$$\begin{align}
\Delta &:= (p^2+q)^2-4p^2(q-pv) \\
&\;= p^4+2p^2q+q^2\;-4p^2q+4p^3v \\
&\;= p^4-2p^2q+q^2\;+4p^3v \\
&\;= (p^2-q)^2+4p^3v
\end{align} \tag{A.6}$$
Thus, $(A.5)$ gives us $(2)$ as before. $\square$

Finding a cleaner form of $\Delta$ was *far* easier in $pq$-form than when sifting through the $22$-term counterpart given in the original question. Seeing components in earlier stages of a problem can inform how they want to be organized. (I suspect that the groupings $g+m+v$ and $m(b-g)$ are meaningful even in the *earliest* stages of the problem, reflecting how parameters in the SEI(S) models influence each other.)

Comment: Nice, both solutions check out! Can you tell me how you did it in the answer so in the future I know what to do? I have added a small addendum, since you answered my previous question(s) you are most suited to answer this addendum, I hope you can do this favour! And thank you very much for your answer :)

Comment: I will give you the bounty but I have one more question that is similar to this. Shall I add an addendum 2 here or ask a separate question? I would use your ideas above in Mathematica however I'm just started learning Mathematica so I don't really understand how to use all the commands.

Comment: @Math: Repeatedly adding tasks to a question (especially after it has been answered) is generally discouraged, but if it's merely yet-another instance of simplifying the Jacobian eigenvalues, I don't see too much of a problem. Please, though, give the form of Jacobian $J$ and substitutions for $S$ and $I$ (watch for typos! :). As I like to think I made clear in my Addendum, the "final form" of the eigenvalues can be unnecessarily-difficult to sift through.

Comment: @Math: As for Mathematica commands: Don't get too hung-up on those. After all, my point is to ease-off the MMA gas pedal to get a better view of what's happening. Heck, you don't *need* MMA for any of this. The char-poly of a $2\times 2$ matrix, say $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{bmatrix}$, is dead-simple to calculate by hand: $x^2-(a+d)x+(ad-bc)$; whereupon applying the Quadratic Formula is straightforward. In your problem, $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are unweildy, so MMA is helpful in symbol-crunching, but you can ease-in to the convenience. Hitting each coeff w/`FullSimplify` can get you pretty far.

Comment: I felt guilty asking. I was following your steps but I must've made a mistake somewhere hence I ask.

Comment: Here is the $S$ and $I$ substitutions: $$e_2 : \left( S_2^*, I_2^*, R_2^*\right)= \left(\frac{N\left(\gamma+\nu\right)}{\beta}, N\nu\left(\frac{1}{\gamma +\nu}-\frac{1}{\beta}\right), N\gamma\left(\frac{1}{\gamma +\nu}-\frac{1}{\beta}\right)\right)$$

Comment: I get $$ A = (g+v)^2$$ $$B=bv(g+v)$$ $$C=v(g+v)^2(b-g-v)$$ Now I don't know how to simplify it further..

Comment: Ok I get to $$ \frac{-qp \pm \sqrt{q^2 p^2 - 4p^4(q-vp)}}{2p^2} =  \frac{-q \pm \sqrt{q^2 - 4p^2(q-vp)}}{2p} $$ where $p=(g+v)$ and $q=bv$.  Can you confirm this is the simplest?

Comment: @Math: "Simplest" is subjective, but I think what you have isn't bad. If you leave $q$ as $bv$, then you get to factor-out a $v$ in the radical (as you did in (iv) of the question), giving $$v (4 p^3-4bp^2+b^2v)$$ And it happens that you can factor-out a $p$ from the first two terms complete the square to get $$v(\;p(4p^2-4pb+b^2)+b^2(v-p)\;)=v(\;p(2p-b)^2-b^2g\;)$$ This may not be "simpler", though. I think your form is fine.

Comment: I will need some help on something similar we did, I have changed my models slightly so I will need to factor the eigenvalues again.. when i post the question, I'll send a link :)